# remove unwanted strings from Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
ID    Website
  1     www.yah.com/?trk
  2     www.gle.com
```

I want to clean unwanted part from the website Url by deleting '?trk' or replacing it by ''

My final Dataframe will be :

```
  ID    Website
  1     www.yah.com
  2     www.gle.com
```

how can i do it known that i might have other options not only '?trk'

Comment: Can you define *unwanted*? How is this supposed to generalize?

Comment: @yatu strings that come after '/'
in this case ?trk

Answer (score 0):

Check `split`

```
df['Website'] = df['Website'].str.split('/').str[0]
df
Out[169]: 
   ID      Website
0   1  www.yah.com
1   2  www.gle.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace '?trk' only and not the '/' you can:

```
df['Website'] = df['Website'].replace(['?trk'],'')
```